# How to do multifield validation in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm able to validate each textbox separately by using data-val true but how can I do multi-field validation? I want to validate first name and last name together. Both fields are required. I'm using guid to generate an unique id so the values can be passed to the controller.

```
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required." name="FormResponse.NameResponse[@guid].FirstName" />
<span data-valmsg-for="FormResponse.NameResponse[@guid].FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required." name="FormResponse.NameResponse[@guid].LastName" />
<span data-valmsg-for="FormResponse.NameResponse[@guid].LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: Maybe Expressive Annotations could help (https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations)

Comment: You cant, at least using client side validation using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` unless you use a `RemoteAttribute` to check something on the server. But what do you mean _validate them together_?

Comment: Instead of showing two validation messages (one for each text box), I want to show only one message.

Comment: Then you would need to create a custom validation attribute applied to `LastName` which also validates the `FirstName` is not `null`. Refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for a good guide to creating custom validation attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate on the server side (at the time when the request is bound to the ViewModel), implement `IValidatableObject`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyViewModel : IValidatableObject {

    // note that we do not have a [Required] attribute here, 
    // or we would show two validation messages if one property is not set
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) || 
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName)) {
                yield return new ValidationResult(
                  "Both first and last name are required!",
                   new[] { "FirstName", "LastName" }
               );
        }
    }
}
```

The messages generated by this validation method can be rendered using `@Html.ValidationSummary()`. It will be shown after a round trip to the server on which validation failed.

You can test whether the model is valid in the controller by calling `ModelState.IsValid`.

[ASP.NET MVC: Self Validating Model objects](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1083/aspnet-mvc-self-validation-model-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel , and validate on submit/focusOut.